# Is there an easy way to run parallel pipeline job on nodes of the same label

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Here I have some jobs that are required to run on multiple nodes. If I'm not using Pipeline, I can do with ParameterFactory from the [NodeLabel Parameter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/NodeLabel+Parameter+Plugin#NodeLabelParameterPlugin-BuildParameterFactory) and let the job run on all nodes matching a label. With Pipeline however, all I can find is the [trigger-job-on-all-nodes](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-examples/tree/master/pipeline-examples/trigger-job-on-all-nodes) example.

With a few modifications it should do the job, but it is still a lot of code. I'm dreaming about things like:

```
node(label='slave', run_on_all_matching_nodes=true) {
    // some block
}
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: I forwarded the question to the mailing-list: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jenkinsci-users/qFIrHZNuvHY

Comment: @wang-dingwei Any luck on this? I'm having the same issue. Basically, I want to run the same job on nodes with a label, but for some reason, the latest LTS version of Jenkins chooses a random node to run the pipeline job.